# how to make text appear on multiple views with one label?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm using a scroll view with 3 views, and I need to place one label that shows up on each view,

the views are on separate view controllers: in view controller.h

```
#import "PagerViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : PagerViewController {

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *View1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *View2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *View3;
```

I've placed them as (in ViewController.m)

```
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View1"]];
```

Should I fix an NSString 
and Outlet to do this?

I need the labels to move with the scroll not to be separate from each other.

Comment: you should make sync for that. think, what should happen if text changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What you want, cannot be done with a single `UILabel`.** You will have to create 3 separate labels and write the logic that will update all of them.

Create the `UILabel` outlets and write a method something similar to the method below:

```
- (void)updateLabels:(NSString *)text
{
    self.label1.text = text;
    self.label2.text = text;
    self.label3.text = text;
}
```

This is just the way `UIView`'s work and you cannot make them draw outside of their bounds.

*I suggest you follow up on more iOS basics before going into complex layouts.*

Comment: Ok, its just if I use 3 separate labels the Label doesn't move with the scroll onto the next view....

Comment: can you answer my other question coming i 5 mins

Answer (score 0):

If you need to separate these views, a well-maintainable solution could be three separated label and one function (updateLabels:) in which the three label is updated to the same value.